# unique file names in php from dir

Tags: php, sorting, readdir, opendir

```
 <?
    if ($directory = opendir('data/')) { // Open dir    
    while (false !== ($files = readdir($directory))) { //Read directory
        if ($files != "." && $files != "..") { //Strip . and ..
        $files = str_replace("122.","",$files); // Remove 122.
        $files = str_replace("234.","",$files); // Remove 234.
        echo "$files<br />"; // Get results
        }
      }
      closedir($directory); // close directory
    }

?>
```

files in directory is: 122.256879, 234.4263, 122.4263, 234.256879

I get results:
256879
4263
4263
256879

But i need unique results:
256879
4263

How to get this results?

Comment: Add it into an array and then you can sort it.

Comment: how to add in to array?

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
    $aFiles = array();
    if ($directory = opendir('data/')) { // Open dir    
    while (false !== ($files = readdir($directory))) { //Read directory
        if ($files != "." && $files != "..") { //Strip . and ..
        $files = str_replace("122.","",$files); // Remove 122
        $files = str_replace("234.","",$files); // Remove 234

        if(in_array($files, $aFiles) == false){
            echo "$files<br />"; // Get results
            $aFiles[] = $files;
         }
        }
      }
      closedir($directory); // close directory
    }

?>
```

Comment: here is same?
$aFiles[] = $files;
echo "$files<br />"; // Get results

Comment: Yes. You can loop through the array and echo. foreach($aFiles as $files){ echo $files . '<br />'; }

Comment: But when i add into html <select><option>$files</option></select>... show all files

Comment: Then you can do echo implode(' ', $aFiles);

Comment: It's ok, first method working perfect. I same did spell error. Sorry.